# Cumulative subtracting a pandas group by column from a variable

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataframe that lists items that I own, along with their Selling Price.

I also have a variable that defines my current debt. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

current_debt = 16000

d = { 
    'Person' : ['John','John','John','John','John'],
    'Ïtem': ['Car','Bike','Computer','Phone','TV'],
    'Price':[10500,3300,2100,1100,800],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

I would like to "payback" the `current_debt` starting with the most expensive item and continuing until the debt is paid. I would like to list the left over money aligned to the last item sold. I'm hoping the function can inlcude a `groupby` clause for `Person` as sometimes there is more than one name in the list

My expected output for the debt in the example above would be:

[image]

If anyone could help with a function to calculate this that would be fantastic. I wasnt sure whether I needed to convert the dataframe to a list or it could be kept as a dataframe. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cumsum transformation and `np.where` to cover your logic for the final price column:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.sort_values(["Person", "Price"], ascending=False)
df['CumPrice'] = df.groupby("Person")['Price'].transform('cumsum')
df['Diff'] = df['CumPrice'] - current_debt
df['PriceLeft'] = np.where(
    df['Diff'] <= 0, 
    0, 
    np.where(
         df['Diff'] < df['Price'], 
         df['Diff'],
         df['Price']
    )
)
```

Result:

```
  Person      Item  Price  CumPrice  Diff  PriceLeft
0   John       Car  10500     10500 -5500          0
1   John      Bike   3300     13800 -2200          0
2   John  Computer   2100     15900  -100          0
3   John     Phone   1100     17000  1000       1000
4   John        TV    800     17800  1800        800
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much for the help